# Setting up VNC viewer for remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, vnc

I have a remote server (Unix) that I've used via PuTTY SSH from my laptop (Windows 7). However, I want to have a GUI to run a certain program on that server. I've tried X11 forwarding, but the GUI it created was far too slow.

So I thought maybe something like TightVNC viewer could work better. I installed it, tried logging into my server, and got the following error:

```
Error in TightVNC viewer: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I ensured no other programs were connected to the server.

Do I need to install and set something up on my server first to make the VNC thing work? If so, how? Thanks, and excuse my temporary cluelessness.

Comment: what type of linux OS type you use.. also, does it have iptables enabled?? it is not recommended to allow such a protocol on a linux environment without using securities such as iptables.. I remember once I did this to a centOS.. If so, here's how > http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6012/setting-up-remote-desktop-for-your-centos-or-fedora-linux-dedicated-server

Answer (score 1):

The error you received is due to the fact that there is TightVNC server running on your (no pun intended) server. You have to install it there. Tightvnc has its own server, but it does not run on Unix machines.

However, there are many possibilities, depending exactly on the brand of Unix you are running. Just Google it.